# There exists $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}h(\sin x)$ if and only if there is a $c\in\mathbb R$ such that for every $x\in[-1,1]$ we have $h(x)=c$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, trigonometry, function-and-relation-composition

> Given a function $h\colon\mathbb R\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ show that there is $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}h(\sin x)$ if and only if there is a $c\in\mathbb R$ such that for every $x\in[-1,1]$ we have $h(x)=c$.

**My Draft**

I know that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}h(\sin x)$ exists, so there are three possibilities. $\lim_{x\to+\infty}h(\sin x)=\pm\infty$ or $\lim_{x\to+\infty}h(\sin x)=l, \,l\in\mathbb R$.

Let's deal with this last case.
Have $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}h(\sin x)=l, \,l \in\mathbb R \iff
\forall \epsilon>0\,\exists\, \delta>0: x>\delta\implies|h(\sin x)-l|<\epsilon.$$

That is, there is a $\delta$ for which if $x>\delta$ the function $h(\sin x)$ is in $]l-\epsilon,l+\epsilon[$.

We want to prove that there is $c$ in $\mathbb R$ such that $\forall x\in[-1,1] \, h(x)=c$.

Suppose $\exists \gamma\in[-1,1]$ such that $h(\gamma)=d\ne c$ and $\forall x\in[-1,1]\backslash\{\gamma \}, \, h(x)=c$.

Like $\gamma\in[-1,1]$, there is $\theta$ such that $\sin\theta=\gamma$. Thus, $h(\gamma)=h(\sin\theta)=d$, for some $\theta$ (this is because the function $\sin$ is "surjective on $[-1,1]$".

Considering, for example, $-\gamma$, as $-\gamma\in[-1,1]$, there is $\alpha$ such that $\sin\alpha=-\gamma$. So $h(-\gamma)=h(\sin\alpha)=c$.

I did this and I don't know how to get out of here or that what I've written so far is $100\%$ correct, even if it's not even relevant to the answer in question. Thank you in advance for the help you have been able to provide me.

Comment: Your, erasures?

Comment: ideas, resolution sketches, ...

Comment: You are assuming $h$ is continuous, but you don’t need to do this. You should also, for precision, define $c$ (somehow) before you declare $h(\gamma)=d\neq c$. Your thought that $\sin$ is surjective onto $[-1,1]$ is good and very relevant

Comment: I recommend thinking why $\sin x$, $(\sin x)^2$ etc. (any simple function in $\sin$) fail to have a limit. Then it might feel easier generalising the argument

Comment: Usually, we don't use $\delta$ but $N$ in the definition $\lim_{x\to+\infty}.$ $\delta$ is used for $x\to a$ with $a\in\mathbb R.$ There isn't anything wrong with using $\delta$ here, but just for clarity, we try to use different symbols.

Comment: @FShrike it´s a good ideia, thank you for your help

Comment: If $h(x)\neq h(y)$ for $x,y\in[-1,1],$ then let $u=\arcsin x, v=\arcsin y$ and then $\lim_{n\to\infty} h(\sin(u+2\pi n))=h(\sin(u))=h(x)$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} h(v+2\pi n)=h(y).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I learned that way, but the choice of lyrics, let's say, is irrelevant, it's just notation

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That's more or less what I was thinking, having a function that takes at least two (I chose 2, $c$ and $d$) different values ​​in $[-1,1]$ and arriving at the contradiction. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, notation has a goal of communicating. This answer is fine, because you've written out the definition which makes clear how you are using $\delta,$ but in many cases, you wouldn't write out all the definitions, and if your readers are learning from standard English texts, it is worth knowing. Also, not all variables are interchangeable. $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)$ mean two different things. @Pierre

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You're absolutely right, but making things clear at the outset is no problem. And note that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ are equal if $x,n \in\mathbb R$. Of course normally the letter $n$ is used for variables in $\mathbb N$ but clearly anything is possible I think so.

If I may, what is the $ax+b$ solution?

Comment: Maybe it will answer $x=-b/a$, but I didn't say what the unknown was! If you answered $-ax$ you would have to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're idea is great, using the surjectivity of $\sin$, but your proof is incomplete. There is also no need to speak about continuity here. Let's use your idea to prove it.

We start by proving that if $\lim_{x\to\infty}h(\sin x)$ exists (and is finite), then $h$ is constant on $[-1,1]$.

Suppose for a contradiction that the limit exists, but $h$ is not constant on $[-1,1]$. Let $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ be two distinct values (i.e. $\alpha\neq\beta$) such that $h(a)=\alpha$ and $h(b)=\beta$ for some $a,b\in[-1,1]$. Now as $\sin$ is surjective, we can find some $\xi,\zeta\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sin\xi=a$ and $\sin\zeta=b$. Now consider the sequences $\{x_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $\{y_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ given by

$$x_j=\xi+2\pi j,\quad y_j=\zeta+2\pi j,$$

for which

$$\lim_{j\to\infty}x_j=\infty,\quad \lim_{j\to\infty}y_j=\infty.$$

Notice then than

$$\lim_{j\to\infty}h(\sin x_j)=\lim_{j\to\infty}h(\sin\xi)=\alpha,$$

$$\lim_{j\to\infty}h(\sin y_j)=\lim_{j\to\infty}h(\sin\zeta)=\beta.$$

But since $\alpha\neq\beta$, this contradicts that the limit exists, and the above proposition follows.

Now the other direction of the proof is trivial, as if $h(x)=c$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$, then

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}h(\sin x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}c=c,$$

and so the limit exists.